# Single central login for front end users from any site

Tags: plugins, login

I have multiple websites with one master site. Is it possible that used register and login using a single username and password on all the sites. the installations are not wordpress multisite,each site is a individual website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very possible.

I've done this in the past if they are in the same table but with the different extensions: (if they aren't then you can merge the 2 tables)

blog 1 (table prefix is ba1_)
blog 2 (table prefix is bb2_)

so you you would have 2 user tables in your database:
ba1_users
bb2_users

In your wp-config of the 2nd blog:  find this line:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Just above it, add:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'ba1_users');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'ba1_usermeta');
```

now blog 2 which was using bb2_users and bb2_usermeta will now use ba1_users and ba1_usermeta.

I haven't fully explored all considerations but this worked really well for me.

Comment: but is the sites are on different domains in different hosting account but on same server is it still possible ?

Comment: different domains is fine but different hosting accounts would be more difficult.  do you have vps or shared?

Comment: i have my own server but hosted the sites in different account on the same server.

Comment: can you give access of different accounts to the same dbs?

Comment: Since all websites are on the same server i think technically it is possible. but i am looking for some thing simple like a plug in or a tutorial as i am not a php / server expert

Comment: it's outside of WordPress. so a plugin isn't going to be your solution.   try what I suggested.  give all the sites the same user and give that user privileges on each dB.  it will work